# Is nonlocal same as static?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, programming-languages

In python, we have a keyword called `nonlocal`. Is it the same as `static` in C++? If we have nested functions in python, instead of using nonlocal inside inner function, can't we just declare the variable in the outer function? That way it will be truly `nonlocal`.

Clarification: `static` keyword as used below in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
int foo () {
   static int sVar = 5;
   sVar++;
   return sVar;
}

using namespace std;
int main () {
   int iter = 0;
   do {
       cout << "Svar :" foo() << endl;
       iter++;
   } while (iter < 3); 
}
```

gives output over iterations:

```
Svar :6
Svar :7
Svar :8
```

So, Svar is preserving it's value.

Comment: some code would help to clarify. `static` is a keyword with quite different meanings depending on context

Comment: Ok, I'll add some code for the context of `static`.

Comment: ... however, that could also be part of the answer, but I have the feeling that you are refering to `static` in a certain context

Comment: btw it can give some insight to compare features of different languages, but rarely if ever two features of two different languages are "same" or equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If we have nested functions in python, instead of using nonlocal inside inner function, can't we just declare the variable in the outer function?

No. If you omit the `nonlocal` the assignment in the inner function will create a new local copy, ignoring the declaration in the outer context.

```
def test1():
    x = "Foo"
    def test1_inner():
        x = "Bar"
    test1_inner()
    return x

def test2():
    x = "Foo"
    def test2_inner():
        nonlocal x
        x = "Bar"
    test2_inner()
    return x

print(test1())
print(test2())
```

... emits:

```
Foo
Bar
```

> Is it the same as static in C++?

C++ `static` variables are really just global variables with a narrower scope (i.e. they are persistent global context which is stored across function invocations).

Python `nonlocal` is just about nested scope resolution; there is no global persistence across invocations of the outer function (but would be across multiple invocations of the inner function from the same outer function invocation).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of `static` in C++ is that it can take several meanings.

What I understand you to mean by "`static` in C++" is a variable that maintains state between invocations. The closest thing in python is the `global` variable.

`nonlocal` limits the lifetime of the value in the nested function to that of the enclosing function. It is a compromise between `global` and `local`.

If you were to omit `nonlocal` in the inner function the variable there would have the same scope and lifetime as the inner function. Unless, of course you were reading and not writing it, in which case it would match the scope of the enclosing function, but not serve to maintain any state from the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

"nonlocal" is not static. Consider the following example

```
def outer():
    x = "local"

    def inner():
        nonlocal x
        x = "nonlocal"
        print("inner:", x)

    inner()
    print("outer:", x)


def foo():
    foo.counter += 1
    print("Counter is", foo.counter)

outer()
foo.counter = 0

foo()
foo()
foo()
```

The output of this code would be like this
inner: nonlocal
outer: nonlocal
Counter is 1
Counter is 2
Counter is 3

The variable `foo.counter` is the equivalent of the static keyword in C++. I hope this helps.